# How to add gif image into TextView or EditText in Android

Tags: android, textview, gif

I use ImageSpan to add image into TextView,but It can't animate.

Answer (score 1):

animated GIF is not yet supported in Android.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

Comment: maybe you can look up Google's ApiDemo , package com.example.android.graphyics   BitmapDecode.java    Movie has been supported since 1.6,

Comment: thanks for the pointer.. but the sample that has been published is just a work around to show animated gifs in a custom view...  but our friend here is looking for a different resolution i believe.
Still thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use multiple images and use animation to achieve it.

Code from the API

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/index.html

Check these Links too:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1e17InAx_w

http://developingthedream.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-canvas-frame-by-frame-animation.html

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

Comment: this is not i want ,i have implement gif decode , and i extend View to draw every frame by gif decode. but how to add gif image into textview.i'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Animated Gif not supported for more standard supported file visit [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

and For animated image have look at this [code](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/13/android-animation-101/)